# Is $[0,1]=\cup_{i=1}^n E_i$, $\operatorname{Int}(E_i)=\emptyset$ possible?

Tags: general-topology

I am wondering if it is possible to divide $[0,1]$ into finitely many subsets $E_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, each $E_i$ has empty interior.

If this is possible, then furthermore is it possible that $x=0$ is not an interior point of
\begin{equation*}
D_i=\{a-b: a\in E_i, b\in E_i\}
\end{equation*}
for every $i$?

I know $[0,1]$ is a second category set. But it doesn't help here.

Comment: $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ and $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$?

Comment: A good answer was already given. I'll give an additional note - by the Baire category theorem, you cannot find such an example for the case where $E_i$ are closed (you have to have some sets who's closure has a non-empty interior, as in the example of Asaf).

Comment: Thanks Asaf, Kavi and GSofer!

Comment: @GEdgar I was wrong and I have deleted my comment. Thanks you for pointing out.